# Setting Suppresses3DTouchGesture to true

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

I want to disable the selection of text on pressing by user in my Cordova app. Tried setting the preferences

```
<preference name="SuppressesLongPressGesture" value="true" />
<preference name="Suppresses3DTouchGesture" value="true" />
```

in config.xml. But after building ios platform, `/platforms/ios/cordova/defaults.xml` has

```
<preference name="SuppressesLongPressGesture" value="false" />
<preference name="Suppresses3DTouchGesture" value="false" />
```

and `/platforms/ios/myApp/config.xml` has both

```
<preference name="SuppressesLongPressGesture" value="false" />
<preference name="Suppresses3DTouchGesture" value="false" />
```

and

```
<preference name="SuppressesLongPressGesture" value="true" />
<preference name="Suppresses3DTouchGesture" value="true" />
```

My change is not being reflected in the app, the magnifying glass still pops up on long press.

Do I need to edit values in `/platforms/ios/cordova/defaults.xml`? 
Why two `<preference>` entries for the same value are coming in the `/platforms/ios/myApp/config.xml`?

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have the same issue (with DisallowOverscroll being always overridden by defaults.xml), but confused as I'd expect this to be a major problem for loads of people...

Comment: I had a similar problem, but with the DisallowOverscroll preference. My issue turned out to be that my config.xml had a capital 'P' on the element (due to copy/paste from a StackOverflow answer), and hence the XML merge wasn't recognising them as the same element. Tricky to spot!